# Programmatically Create Category and sub Category

Tags: functions, categories

i create category have name Brand with this code. i have total 3 categories and each have 3 subcategories.

**how to output 3 category and 3 subcategories for each category?**

> function.php code

```
function insert_category() {
if(!term_exists('brand')) {
    wp_insert_term(
        'Brand',
        'category',
        array(
          'description' => 'sample category.',
          'slug'        => 'brand'
        )
    );
  }
 }
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'insert_category' );
```

Answer (score 5):

If your question if like this:

Category A
- sub-category 1
- sub-category 2
- sub-category 3

Then you would create the following in your theme's `functions.php`:

```
//create the main category
wp_insert_term(

// the name of the category
'Category A', 

// the taxonomy, which in this case if category (don't change)
'category', 

array(

// what to use in the url for term archive
'slug' => 'category-a',  
));
```

Then for each sub-category:

```
wp_insert_term(

// the name of the sub-category
'Sub-category 1', 

// the taxonomy 'category' (don't change)
'category',

array(
// what to use in the url for term archive
'slug' => 'sub-cat-1', 

// link with main category. In the case, become a child of the "Category A" parent  
'parent'=> term_exists( 'Category A', 'category' )['term_id']

));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: parse error, expecting at last line of subcategory,   ' 'parent'=> term_exists( 'Category A', 'category' )['term_id'] '

Comment: second code not working properly can you edit it plz..

Comment: Make sure it's by itself, not in a function.

Comment: @ Gregory Schultz ,, i add complete code here

Comment: Don't surround it with a function and action.

Comment: For last line is ''parent'=> term_exists( 'Category A', 'category' )['term_id'] '        This  error showing wordpress 'Parse error: parse error, expecting `')'' '

Comment: @FarooqAhmad I have edited into your question the updated code that you posted as an answer. Please use the edit link below your question if you need to make any other changes.